# Trying to access JSON API from local .html in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I have built an API and I m trying to access it from a test .html file in Chrome. I m accessing the file through file:///... and I get the local filesystem restrictions. I have enabled cross origin request access on my api but I get the following when I try to access it:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://. Method undefined
>   is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

The request / response headers are as follows:

[image: request / response headers]

and the javascript code I m using is as follows:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
else xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        if (params.success) params.success(xmlhttp.responseText);
    } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (params.error) params.error(xmlhttp, xmlhttp.status, xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
};

xmlhttp.open(params.method, params.url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01');

if (params.data) xmlhttp.send(params.data);
else xmlhttp.send();
```

If I use $.getJSON from jquery the api call works fine but I dont want that. It needs to be pure javascript. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: jQuery is pure JavaScript. It doesn't ever fall back to Flash or include any CSS like YUI.

Comment: Ok - What I meant is without any external libraries. This is because I dont want to force people using the javascript library to consume my API to have to import jquery as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sorry.. I never asked if you need it for testing aka debugging or to production**

open your chrome with this security param:

`C:\****\chrome.exe chromium-browser --disable-web-security`

for chrome:

`C:\****\chrome.exe google-chrome  --disable-web-security`

I'm using chromium but it's should work with chrome too..

Comment: But i m facing the same problem with firefox. There must be some permanent solution I can apply to either the API or the javascript side of things.