# Why is my html request not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to html and javascript and need some help.

So i have a `html` page that has a button on it. and when i click that button i want it to load the `xml document` ( and eventually display some sort of information from it).  I don't  know that I am not loading the file correctly. If i comment out the `xhttp.send;` it will run through. So the line the `xttp.send` is on is where i am having my problems.

Notes to consider: I am writing in `notepad++`, the `.xml` file is in the same directory as my `.html` file, I am using `chrome` as a browser.

Thanks in advance

```
var xhttp;
function functionName(){
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();


    xhttp.open("GET","test.xml", false);
    xhttp.send();
    //xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
    //var temp =  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("alerts");
    alert("something");

 }

</script>
```

Comment: This should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @MattBall - note that the question you've linked uses asynchronous request while this one tries synchronous one. While async is generally better I'm not sure if dup is the right one... (using jQuery.ajax may be even easier but again not what asked in the question)

Comment: If you are loading the page from the local file system, Chrome won't let you make Ajax requests to local files, unless you start it with a flag (I think). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16585514/218196

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov indeed!

Comment: so, what's happening?  are you sure the function is getting called?  what does the html look like?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give the full http path to your xml resource.